# mod_rewrite: How to match file in directory or in root depending on 'availability'?

Tags: mod-rewrite, directory, url-rewriting, pattern-matching

*Hello, long time listener, first time caller here!

Thank you for the excellent advice you all share.*

I have these mod_rewrite rules set up:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1--$2.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

They make */company/services/* redirect to company--services.php. Or /company/ to company.php. Works perfect.

But now I'd like to another rule that if I were to put services.php inside physical directory /company/ it will match and redirect that. And if failing that, look for my initial rule. (And failing that, return 404.)

I figured it would be as simple as including:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1/$2.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

but not so. It will returns a 404 instead. I'm a bit stumped as this goes against how I believed mod_rewrite to work (if a rule does not match, go to the next one.)

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Found it. For reference, this is the complete set of rules:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1--$2.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: No need to append the query string.